# Submitting or updating multiple objects at once in one form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have this form below, where I want to update the same attributes of multiple objects at once.  It's not as easy as moving that submit button outside the form because I've tried that.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXeSn.png

Here's are the **views** (excuse the bootstrap)

```
- @venues.each do |venue|
.row.placeholders
    = form_for :venue do |f|
      - Venue::ACTIVE_FEATURES.each do |active_feature|
        = check_box_tag "venue[active_features][]", active_feature, @venues.first.active_features.include?(active_feature), disabled: true
        = h active_feature.humanize
        %br/
      = hidden_field_tag "venue[active_features][]", ""
    %span.text-muted
  .col-xs-6.col-sm-3.col-md-2.placeholder
    %h4 Contact
    %span.text-muted
      = form_for :venue, :url => {:action => :update}, :method => "put" do |f|
        OpenTable Rep:
        = f.text_field :opentable_rep
        %br/
        General Manager:
        = f.text_field :general_manager
        %br/
        = f.submit 'Save Edits'
%hr
```

**Controller**

```
class SnapshotsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @venues = Venue.where(parent_venue_id: current_admin.parent_venue_id)
  end

  def update
    @venues = Venue.where(parent_venue_id: current_admin.parent_venue_id)
    if @venues.update_attributes(opentable_rep: params[:venue][:opentable_rep], general_manager: params[:venue][:general_manager])
      redirect_to snapshot_path
      flash[:notice] = "Your changes were saved"
    else
      render :show
      flash[:notice] = "Changes didn't save correctly"
    end
  end

end
```

Here's what I tried

**Views**

```
      = form_for :venue, :url => {:action => :update}, :method => "put" do |f|
        - @venues.each do |venue|
              - Venue::ACTIVE_FEATURES.each do |active_feature|
                = check_box_tag "venue[active_features][]", active_feature, @venues.first.active_features.include?(active_feature), disabled: true
                = h active_feature.humanize
                %br/
              = hidden_field_tag "venue[active_features][]", ""
              %span.text-muted
            .col-xs-6.col-sm-3.col-md-2.placeholder
              %h4 Contact
              %span.text-muted
                OpenTable Rep:
                = f.text_field :opentable_rep
                %br/
                General Manager:
                = f.text_field :general_manager
                %br/
        = f.submit 'Save Edits'
```

here's a screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs6Us.png

**Controller remains the same as above**

my params become

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "venue"=>{"active_features"=>["", ""], "opentable_rep"=>"mary", "general_manager"=>"barry"}, "commit"=>"Save Edits", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"snapshots"}
```

I want/need the params, IF they become change, for EACH object, and update them when submitting.

Any code suggestions?

Comment: Are screenshots really needed for this question?

Answer (score 0):

**Views**

```
= form_for :venue, :url => {:action => :update}, :method => "put" do |f|
- @venues.each do |venue|
      %h4 Contact
      %span.text-muted
        = f.label :opentable_rep, "OpenTable Rep"
        = f.text_field :opentable_rep, name: "venue[#{venue.id}][opentable_rep]", value: venue.opentable_rep, placeholder: "email"
        = f.label :general_manager, "General Manager"
        = f.text_field :general_manager, name: "venue[#{venue.id}][general_manager]", value: venue.general_manager, placeholder: "email"
        %br/
  %hr
= submit_tag "Save Edits"
```

**Controllers**

```
class SnapshotsController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @venues = Venue.where(parent_venue_id: current_admin.parent_venue_id)
    if params[:venue] != nil
        params[:venue].keys.each do |venue_id|
          opentable_rep = params[:venue][venue_id][:opentable_rep]
          general_manager = params[:venue][venue_id][:general_manager]
          @venues.update(venue_id, {opentable_rep: opentable_rep, general_manager: general_manager}).touch
        end
      redirect_to snapshot_path
      flash[:notice] = "Your changes were saved"
    else
      render :show
      flash[:notice] = "Changes didn't save correctly"
    end
  end

end
```

This ended up being my solution.  All the crazy params were settled in the name attributes in the form.

Does anyone else have solutions for refactoring my update action?  Seems kinda messy.